# Can you have a doubly nested object literal?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, object-literal

Can I have a doubly nested object literal like the value of "ingredients" below (is the syntax correct)?

```
recipes = [    
            {name: 'Zucchini Muffins',  url: 'pdfs/recipes/Zucchini Muffins.pdf', 
            ingredients: [{name: 'carrot', amount: 13, unit: 'oz' },
                          {name: 'Zucchini', amount: 3, unit: 'sticks'}]
            } 
            ];
```

and if so, how would I access the "unit" value of the "ingredients" objects?

Could i do something like this?

**psuedocode**

```
for each recipes as recipe
       print "this recipe requires" 
         for each recipe.ingredients as ingredients
            ingredients.amount + " " + ingredients.unit;
```

(I'm thinking of using javascript)

Comment: You can have it structured like that but; `recipes` is an _Array_. `recipes[0]` is an _Object_. `recipes[0].ingredients` is an _Array_. `recipes[0].ingredients[0]` is another _Object_. `recipes[0].ingredients[0].unit` is `"oz"`. .. Also, [`for each..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) is depreciated and not wise to use on an _Array_ anyway.

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: @paul ah, okay, that was my intuition. Thanks for the heads up on each. @ Matt Burland Not sure about the syntax yet, I wanted to get an overview of the concept before I dived into the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get all the infos you need from this array([here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwxeS/)):

```
function printRecipes(recipeList) {
    for(var i = 0; i < recipeList.length; i++) { //loop through all recipes
        var recipe = recipeList[0], //get current recipe
            ingredients = recipe.ingredients; //get all ingredients
        console.log("This recipe is named", recipe.name, "and can be accessed via", recipe.url);
        console.log("These are the ingredients:");
        for(var j = 0; j < ingredients.length; j++) { //loop through all ingredients of current recipe
            var ingredient = ingredients[j]; //get current ingredient
            console.log("You need", ingredient.amount, ingredient.name + "(s)", "mesured in", ingredient.unit);
        }
        console.log("Finished recipe", name + "'s", "ingredient list, passing to next recipe!");
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome! This makes complete sense. Thank you, upvoted. Do you happen to have a quick idea how to add up ingredient amounts using `angularjs`?

Comment: No, I don't know this, you should read the docs, they're very well done ;)